# How to use Active Directory in MVC5 Web application

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

In the past, my web applications use a MembershipProvider inherited from `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`. With `OWIN` in place in `MVC5`, I understand we are not supposed to do it the old way.

The problem came when I tried to create a new application. It asks for "On-Premises Authority" and "App ID URI"!

In the past, our custom membership provider just make queries directly from the database. No WS service is in place. Is there a way we can do the same for an MVC5 application?